# VBA: Type Mismatch

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm not particularly good at VBA yet. I am getting the error in the title pointing to the line that begins with `If NamePart =` and it's highlighting the `=` sign. Anyone know why?

```
Public Enum NamePart
    EnvironmentDefined
    FullName
    FirstName
    LastName
End Enum

Public Function GetUser(Optional ByVal part As NamePart = EnvironmentDefined) As String

    Dim result As String
    Dim sysInfo As Object
    Dim userInfo As Object

    If NamePart = EnvironmentDefined Then
        GetUser = Environ$("USERNAME")
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set sysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
    Set userInfo = GetObject("LDAP://" & sysInfo.UserName)
    Select Case NamePart
        Case FullName
            result = userInfo.FullName
        Case FirstName
            result = userInfo.GivenName
        Case LastName
            result = userInfo.LastName
        Case Else
            result = Environ$("USERNAME")
    End Select

    GetUser = result

End Function

Private Sub Command363_Click()

    Call GetUser
    MsgBox "Username: " & GetUser

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NamePart` is an enum, which means to use it for comparisons you probably want to ask if any one item in the enum is equal to some value.

```
If part = NamePart.EnvironmentDefined Then
```

also

```
Select Case part
    Case NamePart.FullName
        result = userInfo.FullName
    Case NamePart.FirstName
        result = userInfo.GivenName
    Case NamePart.LastName
        result = userInfo.LastName
    Case Else
        result = Environ$("USERNAME")
End Select
```

Notice that when you hit `.` after `NamePart` all your enum options appear.

Comment: Also `Select Case NamePart ` should be `Select Case part`